# Protobuf serialized object to json

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have some standard objects that I am using too serialize using protobuf and store in a DB. Is it possible to deserialize the object into generic markup such as json or xml and back to the object type protobuf serialized WITHOUT having the concrete implementation of the class?

```
[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
internal class SomeDTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Id.
    /// </summary>
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string MyKey { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int SomeId { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

This object would serialize into:

```
{
    "1": "asdklfhkajd",
    "2": "Tim",
    "3": 12345,
    "4": "05/29/2015 5:50"
}
```

or if I descriptors come over but not required:

```
{
    "MyKey": "asdklfhkajd",
    "Name": "Tim",
    "SomeId": 12345,
    "LastModifiedDate": "05/29/2015 5:50"
}
```

I was looking at possibly writing something with ProtoReader possibly?

Comment: re the edit: that won't work, or rather: it'll work for a trivial handful of examples only; and it won't handle the example in the question - `WireType.String` does **not** mean a `string` in the .NET sense - it means a *protobuf* string, i.e. length-prefixed data; which includes how `DateTime` is encoded as a sub-message; likewise, `Fixed64`, `Fixed32`, `Variant` etc can mean many more things than just the things shown

Comment: Yeah I am converting the datetime to a int

Comment: that's not how protobuf-net encodes dates/times; if you have added a shim property that does that using unix time: fine

Comment: Got the deserilizer working with datetime. Just have to make the serializer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata Object:

```
public class collectionMetadata
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializer:

```
    public static JObject ProtoReaderDeserilizer(List<CollectionFieldType> collectionMetadata, ProtoReader reader)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject();

        while (reader.ReadFieldHeader() > 0)
        {
            var field = collectionMetadata[reader.FieldNumber - 1].Field;
            switch (reader.WireType)
            {
                case WireType.Variant:
                    obj[field] = reader.ReadInt64();
                    break;
                case WireType.String:
                    var fieldType = collectionMetadata[reader.FieldNumber - 1].FieldType;

                    switch (fieldType.ToLowerInvariant())
                    {
                        case "date":
                            var tok1 = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                            reader.ReadFieldHeader();

                            switch (reader.WireType)
                            {
                                case WireType.Variant:
                                    obj[field] = reader.ReadInt64();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    reader.ReadFieldHeader();
                                    break;
                            }

                            ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok1, reader);
                            break;

                        case "datetime":
                            obj[field] = BclHelpers.ReadDateTime(reader);
                            break;

                        case "decimal":
                            obj[field] = BclHelpers.ReadDecimal(reader);
                            break;

                        case "guid":
                            obj[field] = BclHelpers.ReadGuid(reader);
                            break;

                        case "string":
                        default:
                            if (!fieldType.StartsWith("["))
                                obj[field] = reader.ReadString();
                            else
                            {
                                var tok2 = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                                obj[field] = ProtoReaderDeserilizer(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CollectionFieldType>>(fieldType), reader);
                                ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok2, reader);
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                case WireType.Fixed32:
                    obj[field] = reader.ReadSingle();
                    break;
                case WireType.Fixed64:
                    obj[field] = reader.ReadDouble();
                    break;
                case WireType.StartGroup:
                    // one of 2 sub-object formats
                    var tok = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                    obj[field] = ProtoReaderDeserilizer(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CollectionFieldType>>(collectionMetadata[reader.FieldNumber - 1].FieldType), reader);
                    ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok, reader);
                    break;
                default:
                    reader.SkipField();
                    break;
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Serializer:

```
    public static void ProtoSerializer(ProtoWriter writer, JObject obj, List<CollectionFieldType> collectionMetadata, string name)
    {
        int i = 1;

        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new FormatException($"Collection {name} has invalid object defined in its field types. Ensure your collection schema and field times schema match.");
        }

        foreach (var field in collectionMetadata)
        {
            string exType = string.Empty;

            if (obj.TryGetValue(field.Field, out var fieldToken))
                exType = SerializeField(writer, name, i, field, exType, fieldToken);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exType))
                throw new FormatException($"Collection: {name}, Field: {field.Field} invalid {exType} value: {fieldToken.ToString()}");

            i++;
        }
    }

    private static void SerializeDefaultValue(ProtoWriter writer, int i, CollectionFieldType field)
    {
        switch (field.FieldType.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "bool":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteBoolean(default, writer);
                break;
            case "byte":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteByte(default, writer);
                break;
            case "sbyte":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteSByte(default, writer);
                break;
            case "decimal":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                BclHelpers.WriteDecimal(default, writer);
                break;
            case "double":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteDouble(default, writer);
                break;
            case "float":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteDouble(default, writer);
                break;
            case "int":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(default, writer);
                break;
            case "enum":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(default, writer);
                break;
            case "long":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteInt64(default, writer);
                break;
            case "short":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed32, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteInt16(default, writer);
                break;
            case "date":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                var dateToken = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(field, writer);

                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(default, writer);

                ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(dateToken, writer);
                break;
            case "datetime":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                BclHelpers.WriteDateTime(default, writer);
                break;

            case "guid":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                BclHelpers.WriteGuid(default, writer);
                break;
            case "char":
            case "string":
            default:
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteString(string.Empty, writer);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static string SerializeField(ProtoWriter writer, string name, int i, CollectionFieldType field, string exType, JToken fieldToken)
    {
        switch (field.FieldType.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "bool":
                if (bool.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out bool boolVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteBoolean(boolVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "bool";
                }
                break;
            case "byte":
                if (byte.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out byte byteVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteByte(byteVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "byte";
                }
                break;
            case "sbyte":
                if (sbyte.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out sbyte sbyteVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteSByte(sbyteVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "sbyte";
                }
                break;
            case "decimal":
                if (decimal.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out decimal decimalVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                    BclHelpers.WriteDecimal(decimalVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "decimal";
                }
                break;
            case "double":
                if (double.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out double doubleVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteDouble(doubleVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "double";
                }
                break;
            case "float":
                if (float.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out float floatVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteDouble(floatVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "float";
                }
                break;
            case "enum":
            case "int":
                if (int.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out int intVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(intVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "int";
                }
                break;
            case "long":
                if (long.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out long longVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed64, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteInt64(longVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "long";
                }
                break;
            case "short":
                if (short.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out short shortVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Fixed32, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteInt16(shortVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "short";
                }
                break;
            case "date":
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                var dateToken = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(fieldToken, writer);

                if (int.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out int dateVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.Variant, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(dateVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "date";
                }

                ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(dateToken, writer);
                break;
            case "datetime":
                if (fieldToken.Type == JTokenType.Date)
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                    BclHelpers.WriteDateTime((DateTime)fieldToken, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "DateTime";
                }
                break;

            case "guid":
                if (Guid.TryParse(fieldToken.ToString(), out Guid guidVal))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                    BclHelpers.WriteGuid(guidVal, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    exType = "guid";
                }
                break;
            case "char":
            case "string":
            default:
                if (field.FieldType.StartsWith("["))
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                    var token = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(fieldToken, writer);
                    ProtoSerializer(writer, fieldToken as JObject, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CollectionFieldType>>(field.FieldType), name);
                    ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(token, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(i, WireType.String, writer);
                    ProtoWriter.WriteString(fieldToken.ToString(), writer);
                }
                break;
        }

        return exType;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. Because protobuf (the binary format) is ambiguous, and without additional context on how to interpret fields (which it gets from the type, and other metadata), it is not possible to reliably deserialize data. Even things as simple as strings and integers can be readily confused with multiple types. Also, at the protobuf level, there is no concept of a date/time as a primitive.

To see what I mean: take a binary payload from what you have above and throw it at https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - it has to offer you multiple interpretations of most types, because of the multiple possibilities. And the set of options it gives you is not exhaustive.

You *could* deserialize with `SomeDTO` and then use any JSON serializer of your choosing to serialize it to JSON, but: you'll need the concrete type. I *have* considered adding options to do this using a .proto schema plus a reader, but that doesn't really change what you need - it just changes the *shape* of it.

---

If you know the layout but don't have the type, there *are* options, but at that point it is easier just to *create the type*.

Comment: I dont have an object due to limitations of the business requirements at work. But I can define metadata in JSON about what the fields are named for visual representation.

Comment: @JBurlison it isn't just the names, although that would be nice; it is also the *additional metadata*; is a `WireType` a `System.String`? or some sub-message? Is a `WireType.Fixed64` a `double`? or is it a `ulong` using `fixed64`? or a `long` using `fixed64` or `sfixed64`?

Comment: @JBurlison don't misunderstand me: if you have enough context, then yes this can absolutely be done; but at that point it is easier just to *create simple DTO types that look like the data you expect*

Comment: Yeah I understand the ease of DTO's but I am in a situation where the data is generically generated for testing purposes and it saves time to the company if we dont have to modify the test code, and go through the red tape of getting it re-deployed to our enviorments. with a large company adding a new dto can take a week due to waiting on other teams to make the deployment and get the approvals.

Comment: I do have the metadata for the type and know the properties that are being populated. (deserialized from JSON the user provides)

Comment: @JBurlison then... it should work I guess; I can't help think you're doing it the hard way, but: it is your code, ultimately